# I want to add a check box beside each row in a table using html

Tags: html, checkbox, html-table, row

How can I add a check box beside each row in my table using html .. How can I add it using below lines:

```
<td>    &nbsp;   </td>
<td>   &nbsp;    </td>
```

Comment: by writing the appropriate html ?!? what's the question here?

Comment: what is the html code that I can write it to add a checkbox beside each row in the table ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="name2" />&nbsp;</td>
```

Like that. It's a very basic question so you might like to provide some more information as to exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
<td><input type="checkbox" />    &nbsp;   </td>
<td><input type="checkbox" />    &nbsp;   </td>
<td><input type="checkbox" />    &nbsp;   </td>
```

and so on...

Comment: w3c input "attribute **name** required for all but submit and reset" http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4

Comment: @Dagon It is not required in the HTML5 spec.